# ES6のimportで読み込んだライブラリを子ファイルにも適用したい

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
/* app.js */

import Lib from 'lib';
import useLib from './useLib';

// Libを使う処理
```

```js
/* useLib.js */

// ここでもimportする必要がある？
import Lib from 'lib';

// Libを使う処理
```

たとえば、あるユーティリティライブラリの `lib` を使いたいとき、大元の `app.js` で読み込んでおけば、子ファイルである `useLib.js` でも使えると思ったのですが違うのでしょうか。

実際には、子ファイルでも `lib` をimportしなければいけないようなので、一度importしたら子ファイルから呼び出せるようにしたいです。毎回、子ファイルにimportを書くのはちょっと違うなと思い、質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## そのまま使うのは無理です

JavaScriptのimportしたモジュールはモジュールごとに分割されています.

現状,

```
import Foo from './Foo';
```

は

```
const Foo = require('./Foo');
```

のほとんど構文糖衣です.

そしてモジュールの変数はモジュールごとに分離されています.

よって参照を共通させることは出来ません.

これが出来てしまうと,importした先でモジュールの名前が衝突すると動かなくなり,モジュールを導入した意味がなくなってしまいます.

もしモジュールをimportなしに使えるとすると,例えばライブラリAがUtil.jsを作っているときに,アプリケーションにUtil.jsを追加してimportするとライブラリAのUtil.jsは上書きされてしまいます.

## re-exportと名前付きimportを使えばimportをまとめることは可能

re-exports.js

```
export {default as os} from 'os';
export {default as path} from 'path';
```

use.js

```
import {os, path} from './re-exports';

console.log(os.arch());
console.log(path.resolve('.'));
```

このようにre-exportしたソースをimportすればimportは1回で済みますが,
大した手間の削減にならないので,
素直にimportをファイルごとに書くことを勧めます.